# Why use Comparative for the Superlative meaning: "важнее / скорее / больше всего"?

Tags: грамматика

> **важнее** всего
>
> **скорее** всего
>
> **больше** всего

So far, I've contented myself with putting this down to *just because*, but I wonder why in Russian you use a comparative form to refer to the superlative notion of "the most ... of all".

Comment: Could you give examples? The question isn't quite clear.

Comment: Hi. I'm curious about the rationale for not using the superlative "важнейший всего" or "важнейшее всего".

Comment: Perhaps you mix adverbs with adjectives.

Comment: Важный-важнее-самый важный(adjective ), важно-важнее-важнее всего (adverb (

Comment: the pattern **"the most ... of all"** in Russian looks like **"самый + adjective + из всех (, которые...) / (из всего, что...)"** not **"самый + adjective +  всего"** in case it's relevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In English one can say 'more important than anything'.

In Russian one can say **важнейший из всех**.

Both languages can use either the comparative or the superlative to express the same idea.

Comment: +1. «Из всех видов искусств для нас важнейшим является кино». В.Ленин// "Важней всего — погода в доме" (song)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 constructions with more or less the same meaning (X stands for an adjective):

1. more X than anything (Xer than anything)
2. the most X (the Xest)
3. the most X of all (the Xest of all)

In Russian that will be (using certain adjectives, as I cannot find how to generalize)

1. Важнее всего (более важно чем что-либо) – note that option in parenthesis sounds a bit strange. It might be better with some other adjectives, but I'm not sure. It could be used for adjectives without comparative forma, but I can't remember if there are any such adjectives in Russian.
2. важнейший (самый важный) – unlike previous construction, in this case both options are perfectly interchangeable, even if adjective has superlative form
3. важнейший из всех (самый важный из всех) – perfectly interchangeable options.